# application not returning a valid response to the GET request

Tags: java, tomcat, health-check

It's my first time configuring load balancer and I am facing an issue where my Java application is returning error status code 400 when checking specific url. The expected result when calling following command (curl -I --verbose --noproxy * -H Host: -H User-Agent: -H Accept: http://test.company.com:8080/accountBatch/jsf/landingPage.xhtml) is status 200. Instead, I am receiving following error despite service being available:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Application is not using spring boot; additionally, its using tomcat 7.0.
If I want to return status 200 for the url above, is there any additional configuration needed? Sadly I am unable to find any documentation regarding non-spring boot applications.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl request is broken - hence you get a 400 response. You need to provide a value for at least the Host header (or don't explicitly set it) and possible the other headers as well.